# ppm of CaCo3 of an unknown sample

Tags: analytical-chemistry

A 1g impure solid sample of CaCO3 was dissolved in 100ml of water. After titration the hardness of the solution was determined to be 900ppm - now, how do I calculate the amount of CaCO3 in the impure solid sample in ppm?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unclear whether this is a homework problem or not. But the site rules say homework problems are off-topic unless you include your attempts to solve the problem and reference the source of the problem. You have not done these, so I'll presume this is not a homework problem.

Calcium carbonate is very sparingly soluble in water. A 900 ppm concentration (which means 9% of your sample dissolved) is implausibly high. So I think your sample is contaminated with either a more soluble calcium salt (if your test measures calcium), a more soluble carbonate salt (if your test measures carbonate), or possibly some other substance that interferes with the test.

If you want to determine the calcium carbonate proportion of your sample, this method won't work very well. You'll detect the soluble salts, and much of the actual calcium carbonate will remain undissolved and undetected. I think you need a different approach. I'd recommend first washing the sample to get rid of the soluble stuff (unless you want to measure soluble calcium and/or carbonate). Then digest it in hydrochloric acid and measure $\ce{CO2}$ evolved. This will get you the carbonate content of the insoluble portion. Finally, you can test the resulting solution for calcium content.

Comment: I'm wondering about «A 900 ppm concentration (which means 9% of your sample dissolved)» because $\pu{900 ppm} = \pu{900} / \pu{1E6} = \pu{0.9E-3}$ on one hand, and 9% (or $\pu{90E-3}$) on the other.

Comment: 9% of a 1g sample is 90 mg. 900 ppm of a 100 mL solution is also 90 mg.